# change jframe("java") logo using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

how to change jframe logo of java in netbeans ,what is the code to change the logo

Thanks,

Khoyendra

Comment: So you have the answer, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the [setIconImage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method on your JFrame and pass in the image you want to show as the icon for your application.

[This example should get you on your way](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0246.html)

Comment: Assuming this cryptic question has something to do with JFrames.

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption I've made :)